# S3 bucket given name versus physical name Cloudformation

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I created a bucket with name "my-bucket", cloudformation creates it as `"StackName-my-bucket-{random text}"`. I want to read from this bucket in the java code, what would be the right way to access provided I cannot touch anything in cloudformation.

Comment: Can you share any CloudFormation code?

Comment: Your CloudFormation template for AWS::S3::Bucket can dictate the actual bucket name using the `BucketName` property. If you don't supply this, then you get an auto-generated bucket name. Either way, one common way to share the actual bucket name is to make it an [output](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/outputs-section-structure.html) of the stack.

Comment: @jarmod I can manage `StackName-my-bucket-` but what about the random string. Also, multiple devs will be deploying the same cdk in their own aws accounts,  is there no way to filter by bucket prefix name?

Comment: You can also simply list the resources for the given stack name ([example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/list-stack-resources.html) using the awscli), and find the S3 bucket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you cannot modify the CloudFormation template and it does not have the bucket as an output variable - You can list buckets in the current AWS account. You need the `s3:ListAllMyBuckets` permission for doing so. Then you can search for your bucket name. If you need to search in multiple accounts, you need to assume a role in every account. There is no "ListAllBucketsInAllAccounts" permission.